# Scrollbar moves back to [0,0] by itself

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I want to move the horizontal scrollbar to the creen right corner after the document load.
The problem is that after moving right it moves left back.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    window.scrollTo($(window).width() + 50, 0);
});
```

It doesn't work either (works only when debugging step-by-step with Java Debugger Console):

```
window.onfocus = function () {
     window.scrollTo($(window).width() + 50, 0);
};
```

It works well but it looks quite ugly by me:

```
$(window).click(function () {
    window.scrollTo($(window).width() + 50, 0);
});
```

Doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        window.scrollTo($(window).width() + 50, 0);
    });
```

Comment: Any chance you provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I've found till now :(

```
var clicked = false;
            $('body').click(function () {
                if (!clicked) {
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0, scrollLeft: '800px' }, 0);
                    clicked = true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing object selector for window `$()`:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(window).scrollTo($(window).width() + 50, 0);
});
```

Comment: ready pseudo event should be bound to document only and anyway i don't see how it would fix OP's issue